# Как вывести информацию из массива в php?

Tags: php, foreach

```
$kinderGarden = [
    1 => [  'id' => 1, 
            'name' => 'Sun', 
            'size' => 100],

    2 => [  'id' => 2, 
            'name' => 'Flower', 
            'size' => 50],

    3 => [ 'id' => 3, 
            'name' => 'Rain', 
            'size' => 2],
];

$kinders = [
    ['name' => 'Alex', 
    'KinderGardenId' => 2],
    ['name' => 'Elena', 
    'KinderGardenId' => 1],
    ['name' => 'Ivan',  
    'KinderGardenId' => 2],
];
```

Я только осваиваю язык, не ругайте нуба.

Как вывести запись типа:

Ребенок "название из $kinder" находится в "название из kindergarden"

запрещено использовать функции, анонимные функции, преобразование типов, классы, базу данных, другие переменные.

Comment: массивы ТОЧНО такие? индекс в $kinderGarden совпадает с id? Откуда берутся эти массивы?

Comment: Что-то Вы нам недоговариваете...очень похоже на тестовое задание при поступлении на работу либо на лабораторную по программированию...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($kinders as $kinder) {

    echo $kinder['name'].' находится в '.$kinderGarden[$kinder['KinderGardenId']]['name'];
    
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Разобрался